# My parameterized constructor says my string variable is undefined?

Tags: c++

Sorry I'm awful at programming  and need so help so I can move on with my other tasks.
This is my program below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"date.h"
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    //string thurs;
    Date myDate(thurs,12,2014);
    cout<<"Day is: "<<myDate.getDay()<<endl;
    cout<<"month is: "<<myDate.getMonth()<<endl;
    cout<<"month is: "<<myDate.getYear()<<endl;
}
```

Where is says "thurs" it says it is undeclared, I tried to declare it but it still didn't fix my problem, its why I commented it out.

This is my class, Im not sure if this is the problem:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Date
{
    private:
        string day;
        int month;
        int year;

    public:
        Date(string day,int month,int year); //Param Constructor
        void setDay(string);
        void setMonth(int);
        void setYear(int);
        string getDay();
        int getMonth();
        int getYear();
};
```

and finally my Setters/Getters, not sure if this might be the problem:

```
#include"date.h"

Date::Date(string day,int month, int year)
{
    this->day=day;
    this->month=month;
    this->year=year;
}

//getters
string Date::getDay()
{
    return day;
}

int Date::getMonth()
{
    return month;
}

int Date::getYear()
{
    return year;
}


//Setters
void Date::setDay(string d)
{
    day=d;
}

void Date::setMonth(int m)
{
    month=m;
}

void Date::setYear(int y)
{
    year=y;
}
```

At the moment it displays everything apart from "thurs" - any help and sorry for horrible layout >.<

Comment: `thurs` and not `"thurs"`?

Answer (score 4):

In C++, string literals must be enclosed using double quotes `"`, so you can do:

```
// Note "thurs" instead of thurs
Date myDate("thurs", 12, 2014);
```

Or you can do:

```
string thurs = "thurs";         // Initialize a std::string with string literal "thurs"
Date myDate(thurs, 12, 2014);   // Pass std::string instance
```

---

As a side note, when you want to pass parameters that are not cheap to copy (e.g. not `int`, but something like `string`) *and* you want to make a local copy, consider passing by value and `std::move()` from the value, e.g.:

```
Date::Date(string d, int m, int y)
        : day( std::move(d) )
        , month(m)
        , year(y)
{ }

void Date::setDay(string d)
{
    day = std::move(d);
}
```

---

Note also that since the getters do not modify the internal state of `Date`, you may want to mark them as `const`:

```
string Date::getDay() const
{
    return day;
}

int Date::getMonth() const
{
    return month;
}

int Date::getYear() const
{
    return year;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Date myDate("thurs",12,2014);
```

Note that the parens make all the difference here - changing thurs from a variable name to a string.

Comment: it worked! sorry for the silly question - thankyou =]

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the string variable like this `string thurs("literal");`

Comment: He is already `using namespace std;`, and `"variable"` is really a constant

Comment: This is not his problem actually.

Comment: imho, you should at least change `"variable"` to something like `"literal"` to avoid confusion ;)

Comment: Okay sorry for the confusion, and I thought the namespace was a detail, as he could understand it alone.

Answer (score 0):

Line

```
Date myDate(thurs,12,2014);
```

should be instead

```
Date myDate("thurs",12,2014);
```

Good luck!